# TSeD Proper way to declare Model multi type for 1 property

Tags: node.js, typescript, model

So i have a case that i want to save an object as a json string into database

But it kept getting error and warning everytime because the model is set as either string or object

Do i need two different models for post and get? Or there is more elegant way to deal with this sort of problem?

this is how i code right now

```
@Get("/")
  @Summary("Return List Of blogs")
  @Returns(200, Array)
  async getAll(@QueryParams() blogFilter: any) {

    return await this.service.findMany(blogFilter)
  }

  @Post("/")
  @Summary("Create New Blog")
  @Returns(201, BlogModel)
  async create(@BodyParams() @Groups("creation") blog: BlogModel): Promise<BlogModel> {

    // @ts-ignore
    blog.content = JSON.stringify(await this.mediaService.contentMediaConvert(blog.content));

    return await this.service.create(blog);
  }
```

blog content should be an object from front end, but saved as JSON string for space

and this is my current model

```
export class BlogModel {
  @ObjectID("id")
  _id: string;

  @Property()
  @Required()
  @Lowercase()
  title: string;

  @Property()
  @Lowercase()
  slug: string;

  @Property()
  @Any()
  content: object;

  @Property()
  @Ref(CategoryModel)
  category: Ref<CategoryModel>

  @Property()
  @Default(0)
  views: number;

  @Property()
  @Required()
  @Ref(UserModel)
  createdBy: Ref<UserModel>;

  @Property()
  @Required()
  @Ref(MediaModel)
  thumbnail: Ref<MediaModel>;


  @Property()
  @Default("BLOG")
  @Enum(pageType)
  pageType: pageType

}
```

I sucks at Object oriented sorry

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't clear enough to understand the issue. It would help if you can post the error message and interface of the service also. But I can have some comment on what I can see.

> Do i need two different models for post and get

No, it's not required. You can use one model for POST and GET.

```
// @ts-ignore
blog.content = JSON.stringify(await this.mediaService.contentMediaConvert(blog.content));

return await this.service.create(blog);
```

The issue might come from `JSON.stringify`. It is a good chance that `service.create` use Object, instead of string as argument. So, in a ideal case, this should be `this.service.create(await this.mediaService.contentMediaConvert(blog.content))`

Some other comments which is not related to your question:

1. `@QueryParams() blogFilter: any`. Don't use `any`, try to define something like `class BlogFilterQuery`
2. You don't need `await` on `return`
3. Try to avoid using Json string. There's some modules which can help you to convert between JSON and a class instance. For example, `class-transfromer`.

Hope this help,